# Building Java with ANT from Team Build Extensions 2010

Tags: java, tfs, ant, compilation

I have a basic C# project, but I want to kick off an ANT build (which compiles some very basic java code) and also fires a junit test. How can I find out from Team Build 2010 (TFS 2010 basically), if the junit test fails? If it does, I will fail the TFS build.

I have the build extensions and I am using TFS 2010. However, the documentation for this is not existant.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Exec Activity to call an exe to build and do the tests.

However you may want to look at [Final Builder](http://www.finalbuilder.com/home.aspx) as it integrates with Team Foundation Build 2010 realy well and provides a much easyer interface.