# TFS Build 2010 how do I call an Ant script and/or build flash

Tags: apache-flex, ant

In TFS 2010 build, I have a new build and I want to call an ant script that builds Flash.

**How do I call the ant script?**

Also

**How can I compile the Flash directly?**

I've seen the [Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/2d7c8577-54b8-47ce-82a5-8649f579dcb6/) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3647040/building-java-with-ant-from-team-build-extensions-2010) but it doesn't help me as we don't have TFS 2008. I can't find any documentation on how to use the power tools except the 1 sentence on the bottom of download page saying to create your build the old way and import it (which isn't very helpful).

I've installed the power tools on the agent computer but I don't see any new options in the Toolbox when I'm designing the build flow.

So yeah, i'm stumped :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to call the Ant script by using *InvokeProcess*.
The ant script then builds the flash so everything is working good for me now.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with Team Explorer 2010, you have checkin the TFSBuild.Proj and Ant Script files in source control. Then, you have edit UpgradeTemplate Build Prcoess Template to execute the TFSBuild.Proj file which you have checked-in which inturn will call your Ant script.

If you haven't worked on Building Java Projects using Team Build 2008, you may not like doing these steps.

Comment: Yeah, this is what i'm reading everywhere, but isn't the TFSBuild.Proj  no longer used in TFS 2010? I'm more asking is there a way to do this in a TFS 2010 kinda a way, not a TFS 2008 then upgrade way. Though it is possible that i'm missunderstanding something and what i'm saying makes no sense :)